# Command line escaping single quote for PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd, escaping

I have a Windows application and on events, it calls a command like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "G:\test.ps1 -name '%x' -data '%y'"
```

The name parameter sometimes has `'` in it. Is it possible to escape that somehow?

Comment: Which version of PowerShell?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is actually a lot trickier than you'd think. Escaping nested quotes in strings passed from cmd to PowerShell is a major headache. What makes this one especially tricky is that you need to make the replacement in a variable expanded by cmd in the quoted argument passed to powershell.exe within a single-quoted argument passed to a PowerShell script parameter. AFAIK cmd doesn't have any native functionality for even basic string replacements, so you need PowerShell to do the replacement for you.

If the argument to the **-data** paramater (the one contained in the cmd variable **x**) doesn't necessarily need to be single-quoted, the simplest thing to do is to double-quote it, so that single quotes within the value of **x** don't need to be escaped at all. I say "simplest", but even that is a little tricky. As Vasili Syrakis indicated, `^` is normally the escape character in cmd, but to escape double quotes within a (double-)quoted string, you need to use a `\`. So, you can write your batch command like this:

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "G:\test.ps1 -name \"%x%\" -data '%y%'"`

That passes the following command to PowerShell:

```
G:\test.ps1 -name "value of x, which may contain 's" -data 'value of y'
```

If, however, **x** can also contain characters that are special characters in PowerShell interpolated strings (`"`, `$`, or `` ` ``), then it becomes a ***LOT*** more complicated. The problem is that **%x** is a cmd variable that gets expanded by cmd before PowerShell has a chance to touch it. If you single-quote it in the command you're passing to powershell.exe and it contains a single quote, then you're giving the PowerShell session a string that gets terminated early, so PowerShell doesn't have the opportunity to perform any operations on it. The following obviously doesn't work, because the **-replace** operator needs to be supplied a valid string before you can replace anything:

```
'foo'bar' -replace "'", "''"
```

On the other hand, if you double-quote it, then PowerShell interpolates the string before it performs any replacements on it, so if it contains any special characters, they're interpreted before they can be escaped by a replacement. I searched high and low for other ways to quote literal strings inline (something equivalent to perl's **q//**, in which nothing needs to be escaped but the delimiter of your choice), but there doesn't seem to be anything.

So, the only solution left is to use a here string, which requires a multi-line argument. That's tricky in a batch file, but it can be done:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


set pscommand=G:\test.ps1 -name @'!LF!!x!!LF!'@ -data '!y!'
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "!pscommand!"
```

- This assumes that **x** and **y** were set earlier in the batch file. If your app can only send a single-line command to cmd, then you'll need to put the above into a batch file, adding the following two lines to the beginning:

  ```
  set x=%~1
  set y=%~2
  ```

  Then invoke the batch file like this:

  ```
  path\test.bat "%x%" "%y%"
  ```

  The `~` strips out the quotes surrounding the command line arguments. You need the quotes in order to include spaces in the variables, but the quotes are also added to the variable value. Batch is stupid that way.
- The two blank lines following `set LF=^` are required.

That takes care of single quotes which also interpreting all other characters in the value of **x** literally, with one exception: double quotes. Unfortunately, if double quotes may be part of the value as you indicated in a comment, I don't believe that problem is surmountable without the use of a third party utility. The reason is that, as mentioned above, batch doesn't have a native way of performing string replacements, and the value of **x** is expanded by cmd before PowerShell ever sees it.

BTW...*GOOD QUESTION!!*

---

**UPDATE:**

In fact, it turns out that it *is* possible to perform static string replacements in cmd. Duncan added an answer that shows how to do that. It's a little confusing, so I'll elaborate on what's going on in Duncan's solution.

The idea is that `%var:hot=cold%` expands to the value of the variable **var**, with all occurrences of `hot` replaced with `cold`:

```
D:\Scratch\soscratch>set var=You're such a hot shot!

D:\Scratch\soscratch>echo %var%
You're such a hot shot!

D:\Scratch\soscratch>echo %var:hot=cold%
You're such a cold scold!
```

So, in the command (modified from Duncan's answer to align with the OP's example, for the sake of clarity):

```
powershell G:\test.ps1 -name '%x:'=''%' -data '%y:'=''%'
```

all occurrences of `'` in the variables **x** and **y** are replaced with `''`, and the command expands to

```
powershell G:\test.ps1 -name 'a''b' -data 'c''d'
```

Let's break down the key element of that, `'%x:'=''%'`:

- The two `'`s at the beginning and the end are the explicit outer quotes being passed to PowerShell to quote the argument, i.e. the same single quotes that the OP had around `%x`
- `:'=''` is the string replacement, indicating that `'` should be replaced with `''`
- `%x:'=''%` expands to the value of the variable **x** with `'` replaced by `''`, which is `a''b`
- Therefore, the whole thing expands to `'a''b'`

This solution escapes the single quotes in the variable value much more simply than my workaround above. However, the OP indicated in an update that the variable may also contain double quotes, and so far this solution still doesn't pass double quotes within **x** to PowerShell--those still get stripped out by cmd before PowerShell receives the command.

The good news is that with the cmd string replacement method, this becomes surmountable. Execute the following cmd commands after the initial value of **x** has already been set:

1. Replace `'` with `''`, to escape the single quotes for PowerShell:

   ```
   set x=%x:'=''%
   ```
2. Replace `"` with `\"`, to escape the double quotes for cmd:

   ```
   set x=%x:"=\"%
   ```

   The order of these two assignments doesn't matter.
3. Now, the PowerShell script can be called using the syntax the OP was using in the first place (path to powershell.exe removed to fit it all on one line):

   ```
   powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "G:\test.ps1 -name '%x' -data '%y'"
   ```

Again, if the app can only send a one-line command to cmd, these three commands can be placed in a batch file, and the app can call the batch file and pass the variables as shown above (first bullet in my original answer).

One interesting point to note is that if the replacement of `"` with `\"` is done inline rather than with a separate **set** command, you *don't* escape the `"`s in the string replacement, even though they're inside a double-quoted string, i.e. like this:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "G:\test.ps1 -name '%x:"=\"' -data '%y'"
```

...***not*** like this:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "G:\test.ps1 -name '%x:\"=\\"' -data '%y'"
```

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, altering that to handle interpolation special characters is pretty straightforward. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info! %x could be basically any string (it's a folder name). The string is almost always just letters and numbers, but sometimes it can contain single or double quotes aswell. The rest doesn't really matter, but those two does. Also it should work with spaces.

Comment: Wow, not nearly as straightforward as I first thought! I *was* able to work out a kludgy solution for the original question you asked. However, you're saying here that %x may contain double quotes, and that breaks both with your original command and my workaround, and I don't think there's a way to get around that problem without a third party utility. I'll explain in my answer update.

Comment: Thanks! In that case though I'll probably go with the solution you already posted. Single quote happens more often than double quotes, so  I'll just leave that out then.

Comment: Okay, but keep in mind that my first solution breaks if **x** contains `$` or `\`` as well. The convoluted workaround I just added works for anything except double quotes. And now that I've posted it, it's time for someone else to come along and post a very simple solution and for me to go bang my head against the wall. ;)

Comment: @AdiInbar, cmd can do simple string replacements when substituting in variables. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'm slightly unclear in the question whether `%x` and `%y` are CMD variables (in which case you should be using `%x%` to substitute it in, or a substitution happening in your other application.

You need to escape the single quote you are passing to PowerShell by doubling it in the CMD.EXE command line. You can do this by replacing any quotes in the variable with two single quotes.

For example:

```
C:\scripts>set X=a'b

C:\scripts>set Y=c'd

C:\scripts>powershell .\test.ps1 -name '%x:'=''%' '%y:'=''%'
Name is 'a'b'
Data is 'c'd'
```

where `test.ps1` contains:

```
C:\scripts>type test.ps1
param($name,$data)

write-output "Name is '$name'"
write-output "Data is '$data'"
```

If the command line you gave is being generated in an external application, you should still be able to do this by assigning the string to a variable first and using `&` to separate the commands (be careful to avoid trailing spaces on the `set` command).

```
set X=a'b& powershell .\test.ps1 -name '%x:'=''%'
```

The CMD shell supports both a simple form of substitution, and a way to extract substrings when substituting variables. These only work when substituting in a variable, so if you want to do multiple substitutions at the same time, or substitute and substring extraction then you need to do one at a time setting variables with each step.

```
Environment variable substitution has been enhanced as follows:

    %PATH:str1=str2%

would expand the PATH environment variable, substituting each occurrence
of "str1" in the expanded result with "str2".  "str2" can be the empty
string to effectively delete all occurrences of "str1" from the expanded
output.  "str1" can begin with an asterisk, in which case it will match
everything from the beginning of the expanded output to the first
occurrence of the remaining portion of str1.

May also specify substrings for an expansion.

    %PATH:~10,5%

would expand the PATH environment variable, and then use only the 5
characters that begin at the 11th (offset 10) character of the expanded
result.  If the length is not specified, then it defaults to the
remainder of the variable value.  If either number (offset or length) is
negative, then the number used is the length of the environment variable
value added to the offset or length specified.

    %PATH:~-10%

would extract the last 10 characters of the PATH variable.

    %PATH:~0,-2%

would extract all but the last 2 characters of the PATH variable.
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you're doing! I was a little confused at first and thought you were making the same mistake as Vasili, but it makes sense now--this is what I was looking for and couldn't find, a way to do string replacements in variables in native cmd. I'd break it down and elaborate on how it works, because it can be hard to decipher, especially with the outer quotes confusing the issue.  Unfortunately, this still doesn't allow the passing of double quotes within the variable value. It appears they're stripped out either by cmd or by the way powershell.exe processes the command argument. :(

Comment: In fact, it *is* possible to use this method to both escape the single quotes and pass the double quotes to PowerShell! I just tried something out and it worked like a charm. Way too long for a comment, but I'll post an update.

Answer (score 1):

I beleive you can escape it with `^`:

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "G:\test.ps1 -name ^'%x^' -data ^'%y^'"`

Comment: But that's not what he's asking. He's not asking how to escape the surrounding single quotes--in fact, that wouldn't make sense, because there's no need to escape single quotes within a quoted string in cmd (as your use of `^` implies), nor is there a need to escape single quotes surrounding string arguments in PowerShell. What he's asking is how to escape any single quotes that may occur in the value of the cmd variable **%x**, so that if for example **%x** = `foo'bar`, he's not passing the **test.ps1** script the parameter `-name 'foo'bar'`, which would result in a missing terminator error.

Comment: This is actually a lot trickier than you'd think--escaping nested quotes in strings passed from cmd to PowerShell is a major headache. Let me experiment for a few minutes and I should be able to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating your random single quote variable inside a pair of double quotes to avoid the issue.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass "G:\test.ps1 -name `"%x`" -data `"%y`""
```

The problem arises because you used single quotes and the random extra single quote appearing inside the single quotes fools PowerShell. This shouldn't occur if you double quote with backticks, as the single quote will not throw anything off inside double quotes and the backticks will allow you to double/double quote.

Comment: This won't work, because the whole point of the problem is that the command is being invoked by cmd, and backticks aren't used for escaping in cmd (if the command were invoked from PowerShell, the solution would be as simple as `-name "$($x -replace "'", "''")"`). For the correct cmd syntax for this solution, see the first code block in my answer. However, the weakness of this solution (elaborated on in my answer) is that this treats the entire contents of **x** as an interpolated string.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, I ran into some trouble with a robocopy command in powershell and wanting to exclude a folder with a single quote in the name (and backquote didn't help and ps and robocopy don't work with double quote); so, I solved it by just making a variable for the folder with a quote in it:

```
$folder="John Doe's stuff"
robocopy c:\users\jd\desktop \\server\folder /mir /xd 'normal folder' $folder
```

Answer (score 0):

One wacky way around this problem is to use echo in cmd to pipe your command to 'powershell -c "-" ' instead of using powershell "arguments"

for instance:

```
ECHO Write-Host "stuff'" | powershell -c "-"
```

output:

```
stuff'
```

Couple of notes:

1. Do not quote the command text you are echoing or it won't work
2. If you want to use any pipes in the PowerShell command they must be triple-escaped with carats to work properly

   ^^^|