# Passing argument with one single quote in it to a .PS1 script

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, contextmenu

I'm testing a PS script that will be put into win10 right-click context menu, the script simply accepts path info then echo it to my terminal window. 
The registry key is as follows:
`Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\MyScript\command
@="powershell.exe -window hidden -command .'\"G:\\path to my script\\MyScript.ps1\"' '%V'"`

The script is just `$args`.

For most regular paths, it just running fine. Now I'm stuck to a situation where the file name contains one single quote, like this one: `"D:\John's file.txt"`.

It throws an error:

`The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString`

What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that (that's why I just removed my comments). Anyways, there are a lot of similar questions and answers for this on stackoverflow, take e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958388/command-line-escaping-single-quote-for-powershell

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution myself.

1. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52649221/10467076)  The registry entry has to be modified to: `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\MyScript\command
   @="powershell.exe -window hidden -file \"G:\\path to my script\\MyScript.ps1\" "%V""`

Instead of `-command`, using `-file`, and the single quotes around `%V` should be double quotes.

2.To get the full path, you have to join strings separated by space using `-join` operator like this (if the path contains spaces):

`$path = $args -join " "`

Powershell v6 user could use the `join-string` cmdlet instead.